# How to check Write Permission for Admin from Non Admin with no UAC?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to check whether Admin has write permission for a given folder or not.

it works fine for the current user, but I want this method to give results for Admin process, because later on I go to admin mode from current mode. and this check is needed only at this place.

this is my code for my winform application.

```
public static bool DirectoryCanCreate(string DirectoryPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DirectoryPath)) return false;

        try
        {

            FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, DirectoryPath);
            if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(writePermission))
            {
                return false;
            }
            AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(DirectoryPath).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
            WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
            {
                if (identity.Groups.Contains(rule.IdentityReference))
                {
                    if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) == FileSystemRights.Write)
                    {
                        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                            return false;
                        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { 

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Better to ask forgiveness than permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently gets the current user identity and only checks the rights for that identity.  You should change it to check for the OtherUser's Identity (*Some 'Admin' account in this case*).  You can get the Identity object for the 'Admin' user by calling [`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr OtherUserPtr);
```

However to get the IntPtr OtherUserPtr value, you will need to call some WinAPI code.  Please see this link for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternatively you could change your `GetAccessRulles()` call to get `typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)` instead and then match the string `rule.IdentityReference.Value` to the User or Group you want.

Change:

```
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(DirectoryPath).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
```

To this:

```
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(DirectoryPath).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

Then when looping through the rules collection do NOT check:

```
if (identity.Groups.Contains(rule.IdentityReference))
```

Instead check for the users NT account name for whom you want to check:

```
if( rule.IdentityReference.Value == @"BUILTIN\Administrators")
```